# Question about LSD radix sort

Tags: algorithm

I have the following code:

```
public class LSD{
    public static int R=1<<8;
    public static int bytesword=4;
    public static void radixLSD(int a[],int l,int r){
        int  aux[]=new int[a.length];

        for (int d=bytesword-1;d>=0;d--){
            int i, j;
            int count[]=new int[R+1];
            for ( j=0;j<R;j++) count[j]=0;
            for (i=l;i<=r;i++)
                count[digit(a[i],d)+1]++;
            for (j=1;j<R;j++)
                count[j]+=count[j-1];
            for (i=l;i<=r;i++)
                aux[count[digit(a[i],d)]++]=a[i];
            for (i=l;i<=r;i++)
                a[i]=aux[i-1]; // <-- Line 19
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        int a[]=new int[]{3,6,5,7,4,8,9};
        radixLSD(a,0,a.length-1);

        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int digit(int n,int d){
        return (n>>d)&1;
    }
}
```

At runtime it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at LSD.radixLSD(LSD.java:19)
 at LSD.main(LSD.java:29)
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: It would help if you mark which line is line 19. You know, to help us help you.

Comment: i am not using IDE so i can not figure  where is line 19 i am witing programs in linux

Comment: If you can't count up to 19 you are probably not ready to write sort routines.

Comment: I'm glad we're perpetuating the Linux stereotype. "Duh, I'm using Linux, we don't have IDEs or line numbers or graphical interfaces or color"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about radix sort to know what your code should be, but why it's currently failing is pretty clear. You're calling `radixLSD` and passing 0 for `l`:

```
radixLSD(a,0,a.length-1);
```

When you get to this code:

```
for (i=l;i<=r;i++)
    a[i]=aux[i-1];
```

In the first pass, `i` is set to `l` (0), and you try to do `aux[i-1]`, or `aux[-1]`, which is out of bounds

Comment: thanks but i think in code  something is wrong i  have write this code from  algorithms in C++  robert sedgewick can anybody  give me link where this code is written in more elegant way?